# Profiling and examine memory allocation in a DLL loaded by Java

Tags: java, c++, c, dll, java-native-interface

Here's a brief background. I have a java application that requires about 6 dlls to be loaded. 5 of the dlls were purchased, the other is one I created. My dll is dependent on the other 5. All interaction with the my dll is made through jni.

My dll is apparently leaking memory. I am having a hard time finding the location/cause of it. Are there any tools out there that would allow me to profile/examine just my dll? I am having issues profiling and examining memory allocation due to the face that it is being loaded by java, and therefore most profiles tend to profile java.exe and not just my dll.

Any suggestions on how I might accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you structured your custom DLL such that you can layer java on top of it?  That is, your DLL has its own exported interface and becomes an independently tested thing.  If you have, then you can use a C++ client with your favorite profiler/memory tool without java.

(At least, that's what I did years ago when writing a DLL for use with Java - YMMV).

Comment: I agree with this. If you can isolate the problem to one environment it will be easier to find the problem +1